# PHP MySQL Insert not working without error

Tags: php, html, mysql

i used this code and i didnt get any errors but when i check the phpadmin and my database its all empty no data added to the table what should i do ?
where is the problem?

i checked also my database and table values and my html names

```
<?php
    if(isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )
    {                       
        $name = $_POST['p_name'];
        $price = $_POST['p_price'];
        $type = $_POST['p_type'];
        $des = $_POST['p_desc'];
        $img = 'images/is7.jpeg';
        //***********************
        require_once 'setting.php';
        $dbc = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
        mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');
        $query = "INSERT INTO products(name, price, type, des, img)
                        VALUES('$name', '$price', '$type', $des, '$img')";
        mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        mysqli_close($dbc);
        header('Location: success.php');
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Put `echo mysqli_error($dbc);` after `mysqli_query($dbc, $query);`

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line before asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to put single quotes around description variable?

Change

```
VALUES('$name', '$price', '$type', $des, '$img')";
```

To

```
VALUES('$name', '$price', '$type', '$des', '$img')";
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
"INSERT INTO products(name, price, type, des, img) VALUES('$name', '$price', '$type', '$des', '$img')";

OR
"INSERT INTO products(name, price, type, des, img) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Replare this formate

```
<?php
$query = "INSERT INTO products(name, price, type, des, img)VALUES('$name', '$price', '$type', $des, '$img')";
?>
```

**TO**

```
<?php
$query = "INSERT INTO products(name, price, type, des, img)VALUES('".$name."', '".$price."', '".$type."', '".$des."', '".$img."')";
?>
```

In feature apply **mySQL error** check up to get mySQL error.